# How to create an arraylist from input of a single jtextfield?

Tags: java, arrays, string, netbeans, arraylist

I want the user to be able to type in 10 different names in the same jTextField that I have implemented. I want all the names to be stored in an array, which I can then access in a document. **Question: How do I implement the arraylist?** I got this code from a wesbite. How do I incorporate the for loop in there to ask the user for a name 10 times?

```
 ArrayList<String> nameArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
 JTextField nameTextField = new JTextField();
 nameArrayList.add(nameTextField.getText());
```

Comment: This looks like Java not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

nameArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(nameTextField.getText().split(",")));

If you use other separator in the input please change it accordingly!